# Unable to install firebase functions

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-tools

I try to use firebase functions and I got stuck during the firebase CLI installation.

I have installed node and npm.
Now after I install firebase-tools I try to login an I get: command not found

Here is my terminal message:

> Peters-iMac:GrabItOrItsGone petersypek$ sudo npm install -g
>
> firebase-tools npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module
>   instead /Users/petersypek/.npm-global/bin/firebase ->
>   /Users/petersypek/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/bin/firebase
>   + firebase-tools@3.9.1 updated 1 package in 11.93s
>
> Peters-iMac:GrabItOrItsGone petersypek$ firebase --version
>
> -bash: firebase: command not found

Answer (score 1):

I got it running. But I have no idea how. Several reinstallations. And it worked. I even got my desired functions deployed. Now I Need a deep dive into firebase functions.